# How to change array of object to different object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have Object below which I need to convert into below object format but can its possible to do that?

```
  products = {
      color: 'red',
      type: '2',
      status: 'true'
  }
```

converted object

```
  const filters = {
    color: color => color === 'red',
    type: type => type === '2' ,
    status: status => status === 'true',
  };
```

Comment: And the problem is? Iterate over the properties and replace the values with functions that test for the original value.

Comment: Can you please provide your attempt? (and as previously mentioned, what you're struggling with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this type of operation:

```
let products = {
  color: 'red',
  type: '2',
  status: 'true'
};
let filters = {};
Object.entries(products).forEach(e => {
  filters[e[0]] = f => f === products[e[0]];
});
```

Where filters is the object you expect.

Comment: Why `Object.entries()` when you only use the key part?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the `product` object's entires using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
[["color", "red"], ["type", "2"], ["status", "true"]]
```

Once you have the entries, you can map over each inner array (ie: each key-value pair) using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For each inner array, you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `([key, value]) =>`  to extract both the first and second elements (ie: the key and the value) from the inner array. You can then return a new array, which contains your key in the first index, and a function as a value that checks for equality against the current value and the input argument to the function:

```
[
  [ "color", arg => arg === val ], 
  [ "type", arg => arg === val ], 
  [ "status", arg => arg === val ] 
]
```

The above inner arrays are still in the form of `[key, value]`. As this is the case, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on the above array to convert it into an. object:

```js
const products = { color: 'red', type: '2', status: 'true' };

const filters = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(products).map(([key, val]) => [
  key, arg => arg === val 
]));

console.log(res);
```

The argument name doesn't match the name of the key, but that shouldn't matter as the argument is a variable

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and add the comparison functions to the `filters` object.

Here is a working snippet, along with some test cases:

```js
const products = {
  color: 'red',
  type: '2',
  status: 'true'
};

let filters = {};

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(products)) {
  filters[k] = k => k === v;
}

console.log(filters);
console.log(filters['color']('red'));
console.log(filters['color']('blue'));
console.log(filters['type']('2'));
console.log(filters['type']('1'));
console.log(filters['status']('true'));
console.log(filters['status']('false'));
```